# Workbook.Close() causes "Run-time error 9"

Tags: vba, excel

I am somewhat new to VBA, and I am trying to make a `Sub()` which reads data from a different Excel Workbook. It works by opening the workbook, reading from it, and then I would like to close the workbook again. The last part is what causes the following error:

> Run-time error '9':
>
> Subscript out of range

I fail to see why I get this error, when trying to close a file. I hope you guys can assits. It works if I comment out the `Close()` part...

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim Path, Filename
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, transmitWorkbook As Workbook, revieveWorkbook As Workbook

    'Define a variable for the workbook which is to recieve data
    Set revieveWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    Path = "C:\Test Folder\"
    Filename = "FileToReadFrom.xlsx"

    'Open workbook which is to transmit, if its not already open
    If Is_WorkBook_Open(Path & Filename) Then
        Set transmitWorkbook = Workbooks(Path & Filename)
    Else
        Set transmitWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    End If

    revieveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = transmitWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("F9").Value
    revieveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value = Month(transmitWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("H9").Value)

    Workbooks(Path & Filename).Close SaveChanges:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: why don't you use `transmitterworkbook.close false`?

Comment: As I said, I'm pretty new to VBA. I just used the MSDN documentation for closing workbooks. Your suggestion seems to work though. However I still dont get why my original code does not work?

Comment: try it with the `transmitworkbook` variable.

Comment: Well, that causes the error to change to "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

Comment: Try as `Workbooks(Filename).Close SaveChanges:=False`. An open workbook's 'name' does not include the path unless you are requesting the [Workbook.FullName Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.fullname%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Could you add it as an answer, so I can accept it? That way it might save someone else in the future as well :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by Jeeped, the path name is not used to close workbooks again. The correct code is

```
Workbooks(Filename).Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Thanks you everyone for their help.